# Windows Server 2016 .net Application crash

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis, server

I have recently set up a Windows 2016 Server. I set up my .net application on the server. However, the moment I access the application, the w3wp crashes and shuts down the application pool by itself. 
Event Viewer gives out 2 errors.

1)  Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF8FEDDE899 (00007FF8FEC60000) with exit code 80131506.

2) Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1637.0, time stamp: 0x586fe714
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000017e899
Faulting process id: 0x1bec
Faulting application start time: 0x01d29cca82c75315
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 99612f7d-0679-40b3-aa26-d44ca19c44b8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event ID = 1000

the application is built on .net framework 4.6.1. Since the server is Win 2016 it is shipped with framework 4.6.2. I have installed a test application with .net 4.6.2 framework and an application with 4.6.1 framework (Visual Studio) and they run fine. But my main application gives out the above errors.

I have executed svc /SCANNOW which has found some corrupt files and successfully repaired them. But this has not helped.  IIS version of the server is 10.0.14393.0.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/167#issuecomment-352849188

Answer (score 0):

There could be a hotfix for this RAnand - check out the link to Microsoft support [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2640103/fix-faulting-module-name-clr.dll-error-message-when-you-run-a-microsoft-.net-framework-4-based-application)